# Are the given sentences grammatically correct? Can we omit the highlight TO?

Tags: grammaticality, ellipsis

If you want to get **to** where you want to **get**, you have to work hard.

If you want to get **to** where you want to **go**, you have to work hard.

If you want to get where you want to **get**, you have to work hard.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct and usable?
Can we omit the highlighted **to**, like has been done in the third sentence.
Is there a difference between using **get** and **go** in the given sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can say either:

> get to where
>
> get where

but with an actual place or location, **to** cannot be dropped:

> get to London
>
> get to class

**go** expresses directional motion (or figuratively, some progress).

**get** expresses an achieved state (in locative contexts, a destination, a being-at-place).

> Where do you want to go?

In which direction, *towards* which destination, do you want to go?

> Where do you want to get?

Where do you want to **be**?  What is your destination or goal?

The two are often interchangeable, but there are times when their nuanced difference might apply. A taxi driver is more likely to ask "Where do you want to go?" because he must take you to your destination and travel the route. If you tell a person you're lost, and don't know where you are,  a person helping you out might want to know "Where do you want to get?"  That is, tell me where you want to *be* and I can help you *get* there.

In my own dialect, these two questions might very well have nearly identical meaning

> Where do you wanna get?
>
> Where do you wanna go?

but we can put a special emphasis on the word **get**

> Where do you wanna *get*?

to mean  "Just tell me your destination. I wasn't asking about the route you had in mind."

Comment: Let's say we;re talking about a real place. 
"Can you help me get to where I need to get (to)." If we're talking about a real place, do we use the to at the end of the sentence too? Or is that inconsequential?

Comment: **where** is not a "real place" in the sense I meant.  I meant an explicitly mentioned place such as "to London" or "to class" as I thought my examples clearly showed.

Comment: Oh. I thought you meant in constructions where WHERE is not a real place, like when you're talking about life ''You won't get where you want to get in life if you don't work hard.", where WHERE is not a real place, but a point or level one wants to get to or get on. 

Thank you. :)